# How Selenium handles 3 necessary problems

Tags: testing, selenium, junit, automated-tests, testng

i want to develop a framework. Actually when the framework done, i will package it and send to users(for example jar package). They will not be able to change the source code. But they will change a xml or csv file for configuration. For example my source has before procedure, after procedure and 20 tests. Im stuck with 3 problems;
1- I want to execute 20 tests execute different browsers. Normally im setting browser in before procedure. How can i change browser in runtime.
2- I want to group my test procedures. And then i can run for example only 5 procedures of them. How can i group tests and how can i set someone will run and someone will not. And also i have to do this without touching the source code.
3- I want to make a detailed reporting system. It will log every step of the script. (User login success, menu open success etc..)

Which framework can do these? testng? or what?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

1. i dont see a problem, you can create a brand new browser instance everytime before you start a test, there you can choose if it should be IE, Chrome or FF. You can use parameters for your testclasses, they will be checked in the @BeforeTest and the according browser is opened.
2. groups are supported by TestNG and jUnit, I would prefer TestNG because its more flexible
3. only selenium 1 had a step-by-step logging, afaik selenium 2 does not support any of it. What I did was create a new class "TestElement" which provided selenium method with logging. There I just created a new assertThat which logs fails and success

   ```
   public static <T> void assertIt(String reason, T actual, Matcher<?> matcher)
   {
       Description description = new StringDescription();
       description.appendText(reason).appendText("Expected: ")
           .appendDescriptionOf(matcher).appendText(", Actual: ")
           .appendValue(actual);
       String desc = description.toString();
       if (!matcher.matches(actual))
       {
           TestLog.log(desc, TestLog.LogLevel.FAIL);
           throw new AssertionError(desc);
       }
       else
       {
           TestLog.log(desc, TestLog.LogLevel.PASS);
       }
   }
   ```